# nodejs bad request after register user

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am getting a bad request after I register a user. The data inserted into mongolab are fine, but it renders a page with "bad request". I checked my code like a hundred time and I can't find anything wrong with it.

Thank you

user model

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type:String,
         lowercase: true,
         require: true
    },

    email: String,
    isAdmin: String,
    password: {type: String,
         require: true
    }
});
```

ejs

```
<form action="/user/register" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Username: </label><input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password1" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Retype Password: </label><input type="password" placeholder="passowrd" name="password2" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Register</button>
    </form>
```

route
//register user

```
router.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("user/register");
});

router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    if(req.body.password1!=req.body.password2){
      return res.render("user/register");
    }

    var newUser = new User({
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email,
          isAdmin: "false"
          //password: req.body.password1
    });

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password1, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        //console.log(err + "skljflkjslflksddjfklsjdfkljsdlkjflksdjfkjsdklfjjfs;lk");
        return res.render("user/register");
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/cues");


      });
    });

});
```

Comment: What error do you get on what line of code?  Or if the "bad request" is seen in the browser, which exact browser request is causing that?  You can gather a lot of helpful info from the network tab in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: I can tell you 100% that your call to passport.authenticate is wrong. There's a type there, ")(" instead of "," .

Comment: @jfriend00 - I look at the network tab and I just see post, time, and some other thing that I can tell by looking at the code. Thanx though, I never look at that tab before.

Comment: @Luiz Chagas - I tried taking the ")(" and putting in same function call but got an error.

Comment: In the end I end up using find function. If user not there then use save to save the user. Thank you all. If you want to know my code just message.

Comment: @mac I'm facing the same problem, do you mind elaborating on how you solved your problem? Thank you!